# LINQ to SQL Insert (one to many relationship using custom entity classes and [Association] attribute)

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am currently delving into LINQ to SQL as it looks cool, and potentially much more useful than ADO.NET in many circumstances.

I have used LINQ to SQL before, but I created all the domain classes using the LINQ to SQL Class designer, and I don't really want to use it as I would rather know what is going on 'behind the scenes' rather than putting it down .NET magic. Hence, I have been attempting to create my domain (or entity) classes manually using LINQ attributes.

I was finding it all ok untill I ran into problems whilst trying to model a one to many relationship in my DB. There is a table **Meets** that has a column **LeaderId**, which is a foreign key to the table **Members**

This is how I have the entity classes set up:

**Meet.cs**

```
[Table(Name = "dbo.Meets")]
public class Meet
{
    private EntityRef<Member> _leader;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int MeetId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Association(Name = "FK_Meets_Members", Storage = "_leader")]
    public Member Leader
    {
        get { return _leader.Entity; }
        set { _leader.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

**Member.cs**

```
[Table(Name = "dbo.Members")]
    public class Member
    {
        private EntitySet<Meet> _meets;

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Hometown { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Info { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public ComitteeRole ComitteeRole { get; set; }

        [Association(Name = "FK_Meets_Members", Storage = "_meets")]
        public ICollection<Meet> Meets
        {
            get { return _meets; }
            set { _meets.Assign(value); }
        }
    }
```

Selects work on the Meets table and likewise on the Members table and associated entities are loaded fine. However when I try and do an insert into the Meets table I am getting the good old *'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'* error.

Now the problem must lie with what I am using to store the the **LeaderId** when I am adding a new Meet entity. I am setting the foreign key in my object like so:

```
Meet meet = new Meet();

meet.Leader.MemberId = 1;
```

However, when I am doing the LINQ insert it doesn't seem to understand that the MemberId of the Leader property is the value to put in the foreign key column in the **Meets** table.

I realise this could probably be solved by adding a separate property to the **Meet** class like so:

```
[Column]
public int LeaderId { get; set; }
```

However, I don't want to clutter my class with an extra property that is a duplicate of the MemberId property of the Leader property.

Hope you understand me...
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this problem out, I did have to add the extra LeaderId property to represent the foreign key, then mark this as the foreign key in the Associate attribute named parameter 'ThisKey' like so:

**Meet.cs**

```
    [Table(Name = "dbo.Meets")]
    public class Meet
    {
        private EntityRef<Member> _leader;

        public Meet()
        {
            _leader = default(EntityRef<Member>);
        }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int MeetId { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public int LeaderId { get; set; }

        [Association(Name = "Member_Meet", Storage = "_leader", ThisKey = "LeaderId", OtherKey = "MemberId", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public Member Leader
        {
            get { return _leader.Entity; }
            set { _leader.Entity = value; }
        }
    }
```